# Checkout modules for magento

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento Community Edition for a web store and I'm looking toward onestepcheckout to ease the checkout process. Are there any other module out there that could do the trick ? Is onestepcheckout the best one ? Any idea on how hard is it to install this guy on an existing e-commerce site ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, all in CSS:

http://www.h-o.nl/blog/improved_magento_one_page_checkout_design_css_only/

It should make checkout less clumserdom for your customers.